# Doument is undefined in ejs template in node js

Tags: node.js, ejs

When I try to run this in ejs template, I'm getting error, here is my ejs file looks like this.

//after  tag:

```
<body class="">
    <main>
        <h2 class="heading-main">here it is:</h2>
        <div class="jumbos"
            style="width: 100%; background-color: lightgray; justify-content: space-evenly; display: flex; line-height: 120%; max-width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <div id="dates" style="width: 90%;  ">
                <%= res%>

            </div>
            <!-- <div id="data" style="width: 25%;  text-align: center;">

            </div> -->
            </br>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script>

    <%   for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { %>
       <% let keys = Object.keys(results[i]) %>
        <% let values = Object.values(results[i]) %>
             <%= let res= document.getElementById("dates").innerHTML += `<p>(${keys}) : <span>\t(${values})</span< </p>` %>
                   
      <%  } %>
    </script>
</body>
```

This is the error I'm facing now:
**val is not defined**

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["document is not defined " error in ejs file which is to be used with res.render() in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54025731/document-is-not-defined-error-in-ejs-file-which-is-to-be-used-with-res-render)

Comment: No, it doesn't solve my problem because when I use variable such as `let val = document.getElementById("dates").innerHTML += `<p>(${keys}) : <span>\t(${values})</span> </p>`` in `<script>` tag and when i use `val` in it said that `variable `val` is not defined`.

Comment: Did you put that below the element with id "dates"? Like the comment of the answer says?

Comment: Yes I did that.

Comment: I just revised above code ejs file looks like this.  I'm facing this error. Can you please look into this